# Is there a standard way of a simple in-memory caching code in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, caching, in-memory, memorycache, in-memory-cache

I have an `IHostedService` that saves a reference table from the database to cache in .NET Core 6. Meaning, the information saved will not be changed; it's just a reference table. Though there were probably multiple users who will access this, the data wont be changed and appended. For me this will be enough.

Question/s: though this is simple - are there any standard ways of doing this? (I'm just thinking the data is just plainly saved in memory). Isn't it unsafe? Any thoughts?

Start up:

```
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<InitializeCacheService>();
```

To initialize it:

```
public class InitializeCacheService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public InitializeCacheService (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var repo = _serviceProvider.GetService<IRepository>();
            var values = repo.GetValues();

            var cache = _serviceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();

            cache.Set("ValuesList", values);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

To retrieve cache:

```
[HttpGet("{key}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(string key)
{
    // _cache.Count is 0
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
    {
        return NotFound($"The value with the {key} is not found");
    }

    return value + "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, I use this class:

```
    private IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public FabricaHub(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
```

To set a cache value:

```
    _memoryCache.Set("key", value);
```

To get a cached value:

```
   _memoryCache.TryGetValue("key", out value);
```

I hope it works for you, regards

Comment: Thanks for the info @JaviFrances . Yes it'll work but my question is more of a clarification of that code.